# google cloud project: create using a custom interface

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to create a google cloud project without using the console?

I am building a platform where I would like the user to login (say with Google credentials) and once authenticated, the platform should have the ability to create a project in the users account (by virtue of the authentication) via the platform's interface.

If it is possible, can someone provide general directions or approach how this could work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it's possible, as GCP console is calling APIs to their servers to perform server creation, destroy and other actions

I would think of a few steps to achieve it if you want to do it by your own:
1. Choose the API type, e.g. GCloud, Java, Go or any others
2. Scoping what kind of functions you want to expose to users 
3. Build the new UI

In fact, you can achieve this by assigning proper IAM role, unless you want to build your own whilte-labeling wrapper

Comment: Thanks @calvin zhou. I am evaluating between creating scripts that the user can run using terminal vs creating an interface. If I can figure out the whole process including assigning roles via APIs, then it may be worthwhile to set up. Thanks for the direction.